# Android SDK Tools 22.3 Depends on Platform Tools 19.0.1

Tags: android, eclipse, android-4.4-kitkat

I've got a new copy of Eclipse Kepler and a fresh download of the Android SDK from the dev website. I've installed the ADT Plugin for Eclipse and I've given it the path for the Android sdk folder. When I launch the SDK manager and attempt to install the SDK Platform tools, it says

```
Package 'Android SDK Tools, revision 22.3' depends on 'Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 19.0.1'
```

I already have SDK Tools 22.3 installed. How can I get the Platform-tools and Build Tools? As of now I cannot download any packages from the Android repository.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kind of a work around: By simply downloading the bundled ADT package from Google I got a working SDK folder with included Platform-tools. I then downloaded regular Eclipse, installed the ADT Plugin, redirected Eclipse to the bundle SDK folder and was able to get it all working from there. I now have a standard version of Eclipse with the newest Android SDK!